# Python: sample from dataframe, storing the non-sampled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample, sampling

I have a pandas DataFrame.
Say I want to sample two persons of each group, I use the following code to get a new dataframe:

```
sample_df = df.groupby("category").apply(lambda group_df: group_df.sample(2, random_state=1234)
```

I would like to create a dataframe where the non-sampled persons are stored.

The `sample_df` stil has the indices of the original `df`  so I probably have to do something with that, but I'm not sure what...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `group_keys=False` to `groupby` for avoid `category` to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'category':list('aaabbb')
})

sample_df = (df.groupby("category", group_keys=False)
               .apply(lambda group_df: group_df.sample(2, random_state=1234)))
print(sample_df)
   A  B category
0  a  4        a
1  b  5        a
3  d  5        b
4  e  5        b
```

So possible filter original index values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and inverted mask by `~`:

```
non_sample_df = df[~df.index.isin(sample_df.index)]
print(non_sample_df)
   A  B category
2  c  4        a
5  f  4        b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it! Learning every day :D